# Form Authentication redirecting for Ajax submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I'm working on MVC5 web application. There are two views -

1. Home
2. Login

When user tries to access Home view, he or she is redirected to Login page. Because the respective controller is decorated with **Authorize** attribute.

The Login view is having AjaxForm as -

```
@{
var ajaxOptions = new AjaxOptions
                      {
                          HttpMethod = "POST",
                          InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,                              
                          UpdateTargetId = "content",
                          LoadingElementId = "loader",
                          OnSuccess = "AjaxSuccess",
                          OnFailure = "AjaxError"
                      };
}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Authenticate", "Login", ajaxOptions, new { id = "LoginForm", @class = "login-form" }))
{
    @Html.Raw(TempData["ErrorMessage"])
    ---Some code continues---
```

Now user fill his/her credentials. The request goes to **Authenticate** for checking credentials. Now if some error arise, I am reshowing form as -

```
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ActionName("Authenticate")]
        public ActionResult Index(LoginModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                // Some code for validation and redirecting by use of if
                // But credentials not matched so show error    
                TempData["ErrorMessage"] = string.Format(Login.ErrorDiv, "Incorrect username or password.");
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                TempData["ErrorMessage"] = string.Format(Login.ErrorDiv, exc.Message);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return PartialView("_Login", model);
        }
```

Now as per expectations, the **Login form** (*i.e. Login partial view*) should have redisplayed with error. It's not happening. Instead the Get request for Login form is called. And whole form (or whole View) is displayed in *UpdateTargetId*.

While I checked from Fiddler for the request. The request is made to Authenticate. But then form is redirected back to

```
http://localhost/nsu/Login/Index?ReturnUrl=%2fnsu%2fLogin%2fAuthenticate
```

***I'm looking for help to fix this weird issue with keep using AjaxForm for Login.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is to configure Form Authentication's setting in **web.config** properly.

Configure web.config as -

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
```

where loginUrl is path to Login view. The action name is *Login* and controller is *AccountController*.